# Creating a frequency listing of characters

Tags: javascript, string, object, character

charFreq function that's not quite working out. Hit a wall. I know I may need to 
  do a conditional. Calling the function returns an Object error. I'm attempting 
  to get string into an empty object displaying the characters like this - Object
  {o: 4, p: 5, z: 2, w: 4, y: 1…}. New to Javascript by the way.

Just realized I shouldn't be appending anything. Do I need to do a .push() to
  push the array into the object?

```
function charFreq (string){ 
 var emptyObj = {};

   for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
     // console.log(string.charAt(i));
     var args = [string.charAt(i)];
     var emptyArr = [''].concat(args);
     emptyObj += emptyArr
   }

  return emptyObj 
}

undefined

charFreq('alkdjflkajdsf')

"[object Object],a,l,k,d,j,f,l,k,a,j,d,s,f"
```

Comment: put character frequency into a hash rather than array.  Then you can look up the frequencies by key (character) rather than looping through all the characters and their frequencies just to reach the one you want.

Comment: Very helpful responses. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to set emptyObj's key of that specific letter to either 1 if it doesn't exist or increment the count if it already does.

```js
function charFreq(string) {
  var obj = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(string[i])) {
      obj[string[i]] = 1;
    } else {
      obj[string[i]]++;
    }
  }

  return obj;
}
console.log(charFreq('alkdjflkajdsf'));
```

Comment: Ah, a downvote! Care to give **constructive feedback**?

Comment: didn't downvote from me. your answer seems just fine. i'll post mine just to show my coding style. will upvote you meanwhile

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead: you need to create an object property first, then increment it. What you do, is implicitly convert the object to a string and concatenate more string data to it (using `+=` and `concat`).

This is a simple approach:

```
function charFreq(string){ 
  var emptyObj={};
    for(var i=0; i<string.length; i++) {
      if(!emptyObj.hasOwnProperty(string[i])){ // if property doesn’t exist
        emptyObj[string[i]]=0;                 // create it and set to 0
      }
      emptyObj[string[i]]++;                   // increment it
    }
  return emptyObj;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for breaking this down.

Answer (score 0):

A modified version of Richard Kho's code:

```
   function charFreq(string) {
      var obj = {};

      for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        var c=string[i];
        if (c=='') continue;
        if (obj[c]==null) obj[c]=0;
        obj[c]++;
      }

      return obj;
    }
```